# How to configure HTTPS with Ktor in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, https, backend, ktor

I'm working on a Kotlin project using Ktor as the backend framework, and I need to configure HTTPS for secure communication between the server and clients. I've tried following the Ktor documentation and various online resources, but I'm still having trouble getting it to work.

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

-Generating a self-signed SSL certificate using keytool and adding it to the application resources.

-Configuring the application engine to use HTTPS by adding an SSL connector with the keystore path and password.

-Setting up a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS using a custom routing function.

However, when I try to access the server using HTTPS, I get an SSLHandshakeException error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if there's something else I need to configure.

Can someone provide a step-by-step guide or example code for configuring HTTPS with Ktor in Kotlin? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you read the SSL article in the documentation https://ktor.io/docs/ssl.html?